# How can I get this nested for loop to populate my matrix p.F2.D with something other than NA values?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, nested-loops

```
# using a nested for loop to calculate the probability of detecting a disease given a positive test for four different prevalence rates of said disease and 100 different false positive rates
# p(D|F2)
p.D.F2 <- 0.7
# p(F2) : {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}

p.F2 <- seq(0.2, 0.8, by = 0.2)

# P(D|notF2) : 100 linearly spaced intervals ranging from 0.01 to 0.5

p.D.not.F2 <- seq(0.01, 0.5, by = 0.005)

# create an empty matrix to populate 

p.F2.D <- matrix(nrow = length(p.F2), ncol = length(p.D.not.F2))

# Loop across values of one parameter

for (i in 1:length(p.F2)) {

# Loop across values of other parameter

for (j in 1:length(p.D.not.F2)) {

# Fill in your calculation of p.F2.D on the right-hand side (using Bayes theorem)


p.F2.D[i,j] <- c(prod(p.D.F2[j], p.F[i])/p.D)
  }
}

# this loop as I have it keeps returning a matrix with only the first run through the loop populated and the others are all "NA"
         

# 0.9130435   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 

# please let me know what it is that i'm missing to get this to run!!
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, not `p.F ` is missing.

Comment: Also p.D is missing